# Postagens em página especifica Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou trabalhando com o wordpress e estou personalizando o index mantendo o topo e o rodapé:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

só que, quando eu vou nas configurações e aponto a página "Blog" como a página de postagens elas não aparecem (imagem abaixo).

[image: configuração do wordpress]

Onde que eu aponto isso manualmente?
Ou eu vou ter que criar e configurar uma página "blog.php" na página do tema?

Alias, não sei se é correto alterar a página inicial direto no index do tema... 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa! Achei a resposta e deu certo.

Primeiro fui na pasta do meu tema e copiei o page.php(funciona com o index também) e renomeie para blog.php

Após isso defini ele como um template "Blog" de página logo no início do arquivo:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
get_header(); ?>
```

Fui na página que criei e mudei a seguinte opção na edição rápida:
[image: mudando blog]

E fiz a ultima alteração em "Opções > Leitura":

[image: configurações]

Como eu queria exibir todos os posts, só isso já bastou :D

Comment: Em vez de renomear, é melhor fazer uma cópia. A `page.php` é usada como default para qualquer página que não tenha *Modelo* definido (o "Modelo por Omissão" que aparece ali no screenshot).

Comment: Valeu a dica manm, não sabia.